# Why a lower/higher than resonant capacitor is required in tesla coil design?

Tags: tesla-coil

People are telling me that the primary tuned LC circuit should have a capacitor a little higher or lower than resonance, but not at it. Why is this the case? Don't you want the most power you can get?

Comment: Do you have a link to this on the net?

Comment: if it resonates, who knows how crazy stuff will get? If it stays in known bounds, you can design for it properly. Avoid resonating unless that is exactly what you design it to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tesla coils are homebrew projects, since they are not commercially made.  Sometimes re-purposed components are operated near or beyond their capabilities.  Apparently neon sign transformers are operated near their breakdown voltage.  So, de-tuning the circuit is sometimes done to prolong the life of the components.   It's true that at resonance, you will get the most "power" (or voltage, or whatever you seek) out of it, but your parts could burn out at this point.  Use better parts, and you can operate it at resonance.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the output streamer is part of the topload capacitance. The streamers will lower the secondary resonance. I have heard a foot is equal to 2pf . So you want your primary lower tuned a little, so the streamers don't detune to fast.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, say you have a 15000 volt neon transformer to charge your capacitor to 15000 volts. That will work fine, if you use ltr cap. If you use a resonant cap, you get a condition of resonant rise, where in just a few micro seconds your once 15000 volts is now 75000 volts or higher. What is your transformer and cap rated for...? They will fry very quick. You can avoid with safety gaps in place, but if they miss a beat, well you know what happens. So ltr cap prevents this, 15000 in 15000 out roughly.